# What Grails plugin to use to grab data from url that need authentication

Tags: url, authentication, grails, authorization

I'm trying to grab JSON file from the url, but url needs authentication.

What methods/plugins can I use to pass the authentication header in my Grails application?

It would be nice to direct me to sources that can help me figure this out.

P.S. I'm using Grails 2.3.7

Comment: I think Client Rest Builder could help you (https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder)

Comment: @cantoni
I've already looked at that, but where is the proper documentation for Rest Client Builder?
Right now I want to pass my id and password..

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/jenkins/JenSummaryService.groovy try this it grabs various data including JSON from jenkins after authenticating or not